# import large JSON file into mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport, nosql

Due to some migrations and change in server, I have to change my Mongo database from old to new data is also need to transfer but data is too much now almost ~4GB of each file. In total, I have almost 20 files.
My problem is when I upload to new collections it says "tostring" error. I read and come to know there is the limit from MongoDB of 16mb to import a file.
How can I import JSON file into MongoDB? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for mongoexport it says:

> Avoid using mongoimport and mongoexport for full instance production
>   backups. They do not reliably preserve all rich BSON data types,
>   because JSON can only represent a subset of the types supported by
>   BSON. Use mongodump and mongorestore as described in MongoDB Backup
>   Methods for this kind of functionality.

Rather than using `mongoexport` to create a json file and then `mongoimport` to reimport it, you should use `mongodump` and `mongorestore`.